# Trying to edit Profile

Tags: support, profile-page

I wish to delete a link in my profile. And when I do - it shows two user id numbers? How can this be? One has the link removed and the other not. Please look:

https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/15161/geula613?tab=profile

and this is the other profile
https://stackexchange.com/users/11205172/geula613

Now, please tell me how this happened? And how to fix it. Thanks much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first link is your profile on Mi Yodeya.  This is what you edited.

The second is your network-wide profile.  The "about" section there doesn't automatically update.  You could have accounts on several sites with different profile text on each; this profile used to update automatically to your oldest account, but many people found that to be undesirable.  So eventually SE decoupled that, and you now have to explicitly update it.  (I know -- for just one account this seems like an unnecessary extra step, but it's not smart enough to detect and handle that case.)

You can update your network profile by clicking on the "update profile info" link under the text on the network profile:

[image: update profile link]